# Will the new snap package make `Ubuntu Make` obsolete?

Tags: ubuntu-core, ubuntu-make, snap

[Ubuntu Make](https://github.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-make) is a tool to install some latest versions of popular developers tools. At least more recent versions then the repository is offering. It is invaluable for e.g. Arduino IDE.

If I understand `snaps` on 16.04 correctly, the new way would be packaging Arduino IDE as a `snap package`. Will `snap` supersede `Ubuntu Make?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The long term idea is to have Ubuntu Make packaging snaps. The whole UI and tests have been carefully designed to cope with that case.

So, what would happen is Ubuntu Make running daily on some server, grabbing latest upstream. If version changes, it will package it as a `snap` and then run the same exhaustive testsuite.

If all tests pass (no regression), then, the new `snap package` is published!